# Loop through date in SQL Server and exclude the dates within a range of one week

Tags: sql, loops, sql-server-2008, range, gaps-and-islands

I have a set of data where I want to loop through them and if I have dates within a range of one week (7 days) i want to only count the first 1 of them.

Please see below table.

For example, for customer `Bell`, the date 10/25/2023 should be excluded or flagged as 0, because there is a date for Bell in 10/22/2023 and only 3 days between them.

I have this dataset in a table in SQL and I'm not familiar on how to do it in SQL Server.

Thank you and appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @scotthunter actually as i write in the post.. i'm not familiar with loop in sql.. So i hope i can find someone here can help me. I dont even know how it works here in sql.. Its totally different from java way .

Comment: Suppose someone had the dates 1/1/23, 1/7/23 and 1/13/23; what should they each be flagged, and why?

Comment: @scotthunter The date 1/1/23 flaged 1.. The date 1/7/23 flaged 0 because the range between 1/1 and 1/7 is less than 7days... The date1/13/23 flaged 0 also because the range between 1/7 and 1/13 is less than 7 days... So only the first only need to be Count 1/1/23.. Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't just flagging 1/7/23 as 1 or just 1/13/23 as 1 be alternative correct solutions?

Comment: @scotthunter i want to only Count 1 date in a range of 7 days.. So every dates located between 7 days O only need one of them and the frist one.

Comment: Then "... and the first one" should be in your definition of the problem.

Comment: If you're thinking "loop" and "database" at the same time, you need to go back to the drawing board. There is no reason to use a loop to solve this. Instead, this class of problem is solved using what we call a **gaps and islands** approach.

Comment: Also, SQL Server 2008 has been **end of life** for nearly 5 years now. That means it hasn't had any updates in that time... **not even critical security patches!** It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.